# Unable to trigger chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener with google chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm a bit stuck here and was wondering if anyone can point out where I might be wrong.

I am simply trying to make the body color change to red on click of the app icon.

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Bagde",
    "description": "",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Test",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

popup.html

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>Some Content ..</p>
    </body>

</html>
```

popup.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    //Get Reference to Functions
    backGround = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
    //Call Function
    backGround.updateIcon();
  });
```

background.js

```
var i = 1;

function updateIcon() {
    i = 1;
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
        text: 'Test'
    });
    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
        popup: "popup.html"
    });
}


chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({
    color: [200, 0, 0, 100]
});

window.setInterval(function () {
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
        text: String(i)
    });
    i++;
}, 4000);

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
        {code:"document.body.bgColor='red'"});
});
```

any ideas what I may be doing wrong? Thanks for taking your time to reading this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you define `default_popup`, you can't have a listener for `browserAction.onClicked`. In this case you can simply add the code in your handler to your `popup.js`.

**EDIT**: That is, add to `popup.js` the following:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code:"document.body.bgColor='red'"});
```

Comment: hi @rsanchez so are you saying to remove what ever I have in popup.js and replace it with chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
 chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
  {code:"document.body.bgColor='red'"});
});? because doing so still doesn't make my page red on click

Comment: @BaconJuice no, just the code inside your handler function. See my update.

Comment: Adding that to my popup.js doesn't render my page red on click. Any ideas? thanks for your help btw!

Comment: @BaconJuice I think you need to add the `tabs` permission to your manifest. Also, check the console of your popup window for errors.

Comment: @BaconJuice you also need to add the urls of the pages you want to be able to turn red to the permissions. If you want it to work on any page, add `<all_urls>`

Comment: @BaconJuice now you can use the `activeTab` permission instead of `tabs` and `<all_urls>` if your extension only acts on the current tab when the browser action is invoked. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab

Comment: "_you can't have a listener for browserAction.onClicked_"

Here's the doc that verifies this:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked