# Chrome extension browser action event not firing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to make chrome extension which opens all my favourite websites when I click on it.

Currently my manifest.json is:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Soical_open",
  "description": "This extension opens all my favorite social sites once",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

and my background.js is:

```
var queue = ['www.fb.com', 'www.gmail.com' , 'www.quora.com'];
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  for (var i=0; i<queue[1].length; ++i)
    chrome.tabs.create({"url": queue[i], "active": false, "index":tab.index+i});
});
```

When I load this extension and click on it, nothing happens. What is that I am doing wrong? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not create a [Browser Action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction).

It's messy since Chrome [introduced mandatory icons in toolbar for all extensions](https://chrome.googleblog.com/2016/01/new-year-new-chrome.html), but if you don't declare a `"browser_action"` section in the manifest, that dummy "button" doesn't fire any event. Clicking it just opens a context menu.

Just supply an icon and add a `"browser_action"` section to the manifest, and it will work (do not specify a popup, just the icon/title, otherwise `onClicked` [will not fire](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18766886/934239)).

Comment: Maybe you can even get away with an empty `"browser_action"` section - but it must be present.